# Defining the unknown characteristics of quadrilateral with known angle, known side, variable side

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

In the quadrilateral shown below, I have two known angles ($\angle ABC = 135^\circ$ and $\angle DAB = 90^\circ$) and two known sides ($AB$ and $AD$). The side lengths have the following constraint: $AB + AD = BC + CD$.

[image]

> I am trying find equations for the side lengths $BC$ and $CD$ based on $AB$ and $AD$.

I have tried working through the triangles using sine and cosine method, but unfortunately it has been a long time since I used my high school trig and algebra and I haven't figured it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: drop a perpendicular to $AD$ from $C$, call the intersection point $H$. This should get you there.

Comment: I've tried that but I seem to get to the point where I just have the unknown lengths DH and HC. I can find AB and BC in terms of the lengths DH and HC but I can't relate it back to the length DC.

Comment: Hmm, works out on my end. Why don't you put your work in the question and then I can help you figure out where you've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This first solution doesn't work out.** Skip past the horizontal divider for one that works, or if you can see why this breaks, please post a comment!

As mentioned in the hint in the comments, drop a perpendicular to $AD$ from $C$ and call the resulting intersection $H$. We may then draw in a line parallel to $AD$ passing through $B$ which intersects $CH$ at $G$. We then observe the following relations:

- First, as $H$ is inside the segment $AD$, we have $DH = AD - AH$.
- Next, by examining the 45-45-90 triangle $BCG$ and noting that $BG=AH$, we get $AH=BC/\sqrt{2}$ and $CH = AB + BC/\sqrt{2}$.
- Then, as $CDH$ is a right triangle, we have $CH^2+DH^2=CD^2$.
- Finally, we recall the equation $BC+CD=AB+AD$ from the problem statement and rewrite it as $CD = AB+AD-BC$.

Now, substituting in to equation relating $CH$, $DH$, and $CD$ we get

$$(AB+BC/\sqrt{2})^2 + (AD-BC/\sqrt{2})^2= (AB+AD-BC)^2$$

which after some light algebra gives us that

$$ BC = \frac{2(AB)(AD)}{(2+\sqrt{2})(AB+AD)} $$ and then we're finished as we already know both $AB$ and $AD$.

---

Somehow the above solution produces something incorrect in an example. Let's try again to see where we made a mistake.

The condition $AB+AD=BC+CD$ with $A,B,D$ fixed as in the problem determines an ellipse of possible locations for $C$. Namely, if we set $A=(0,0)$, $B=(0,b)$, and $D=(d,0)$ then the locus of $C=(x,y)$ satisfies the equation $\sqrt{x^2+(y-b)^2}+\sqrt{(x-d)^2+y^2} = b+d$, or equivalently in standard form for an ellipse, $$ (b^2+2bd)x^2+(2bd)xy+(2bd+d^2)y^2+(-2b^2d-2bd^2)x+(-2b^2d-2bd^2)y=0$$

Enforcing that the angle $ABC$ is $135$ means that $y=x+b$. Substituting this in to the equation, we see that $(b^2+6bd+d^2)x^2+(2b^2d-2bd^2)x-b^2d^2=0$, so $x=\frac{(1\pm\sqrt{2})bd^2+(-1\pm\sqrt{2})b^2d}{b^2+6bd+d^2}$, and $BC=\sqrt{2}x=\frac{(\sqrt{2}\pm2)bd^2+(-\sqrt{2}\pm2)b^2d}{b^2+6bd+d^2}$ and we can backsolve from here.

Applying this to the example of $b=100,d=40$ from the comment does indeed produce $C\approx(15.5,115.5)$ which gives $BC\approx21.93$, $CD\approx 118.07$ and both ways of calcuating $CD$ give the same result.

My best guess for an explanation as to what's gone wrong here is that somehow when putting the equations together, the $(BC)^2$ terms in the first solution canceled when they shouldn't have. I can't remember the name for why this happens - I know I've seen it once or twice before, but not in a while. If any reader can shed some light on this, please drop a line in the comments.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks very much for your help. The solution seems right but it doesn't seem to work when I plug in some numbers. I checked first in Geogebra and then worked through the triangles, for instance:

If AB = 100 and AD = 40 then your solution comes out with BC = 16.74, making CD = (100+40)-16.74 = 123.26. If I work through the triangles I have

BG = BC/√2 = 16.74/√2 = 11.83 = AH = CG
DH = AD - AH = 40 - 11.83 = 28.17
CH = CG + AB = 11.83 + 100 = 111.83

CD = √(DH^2+CH^2) = √(28.17^2+11.83^2) = 115.33

Let me know if I've gone wrong somewhere. Thanks again

Comment: 1. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it makes things much more readable. 2. Huh, somehow it's putting things on the wrong sides: if you find $BC$, determine $CD$ from that, and then finally determine $DH$ from there, you get that $DH>40$ so somehow $H$ is on the wrong side of $A$. I'm currently looking to see where my mistake might be.

Comment: I've supplied what I believe to be a correct solution which even gives the right answer in the case of the example. Still not totally sure how to fix the first one, so I'm leaving it up with a disclaimer so that if someone does know, they can tell us.